# Shaped Queries Hit Database Multiple Times

Tags: entity-framework

Trying to tune an EF Core 1.0 query against SQL Server 2016.  Run into the following issues:

1. When trying to avoid hitting the db multiple times, I try to return all data at once (using multiple "From" clauses).  This approach can result in Cartesian products and, therefore, a prohibitive amount of data is returned.
2. Another approach is to avoid returning the massive amounts of data by using "Include" and "ThenInclude" statements.  This returns a small amount of data but it also hits the database too many times (to shape the data).

I'm starting to think that a stored procedure would be the best of both worlds but then I lose the advantages of Linq.  Any concerns/advice?